# LINQ to Entities complex query

Tags: linq, frameworks, entity

> Is it possible ...???  I have 4 DropDownLists on my main page and the
>   user may select from any, all or some of
>   the DropDownLists.  I am capturing their selection (or non-selection) using a SESSION
>   variable.  What I would like to be able to do is pass the session
>   variable values to my Data Access Layer and build a WHERE clause
>   (maybe using StringBuilder) and then place that variable SOMEHOW into
>   my query expression.  Is that possible???  Sorry, I'm a newbie.  Thanks ~susan~

```
public class DLgetRestaurants
    {
        FVTCEntities db = new FVTCEntities();

        public List<RESTAURANT> getRestaurants(string cuisineName, string priceName, string cityName)

        [Build a string based on the values passed to the function]

        {
            var cuisineID = db.CUISINEs.First(s => s.CUISINE_NAME == cuisineName).CUISINE_ID;

            List<RESTAURANT> result = (from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs.Include("CITY").Include("CUISINE").Include("Price") 
                                       where **[USE STRINGBUIDER EXPRSSION HERE]**
                                       select RESTAURANT).ToList();


             return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this in the past using the [Dynamic Linq Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Comment: You have to add a reference to System.Linq.Dynamic. Then you can write your query like this db.Restaurants.Where(myFilter). Myfilter is a string that can contain something like "cuisine_name = 'Italian'"

Comment: Wow, thank you!  This was a big help in simplifying my code.  Regards, ~susan~

Answer (score 1):

You can compose Where conditions which are linked by a logical AND relatively easy in LINQ extension method syntax:

```
var query = db.RESTAURANTs.Include("CITY").Include("CUISINE").Include("Price");

if (userHasSelectedInDDL1)
    query = query.Where(r => r.PropertyForDDL1 == ValueFromDDL1);

if (userHasSelectedInDDL2)
    query = query.Where(r => r.PropertyForDDL2 == ValueFromDDL2);

if (userHasSelectedInDDL3)
    query = query.Where(r => r.PropertyForDDL3 == ValueFromDDL3);

if (userHasSelectedInDDL4)
    query = query.Where(r => r.PropertyForDDL4 == ValueFromDDL4);

List<RESTAURANT> result = query.ToList();
```

For a much more flexible solution to build queries dynamically the Dynamic LINQ Library recommended by boca is probably the better choice.